# How to trim the spaces for `\BODY` in `\NewEnviron`

Tags: environments, environ

The following is the code of `\ansproof` environment (a NavyBlue colored `\proof` environment) that I have defined.
The issue is that, in the original version of `\proof`, `\begin{proof}\n\n\n\end{proof}` (replace `\n` with typing 'enter'), those empty lines will be ignored, but this is not the case of my `\ansproof` environment, since `\BODY` is still readed with those `\n`, and not recognized as `\empty`. This caused the QED symbol to appear on another line when the proof is empty.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ansproofbase}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\hfill\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\qed}}%
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textit{#1.}}]\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\NewEnviron{ansproof}{%
    \ifx\BODY\empty%
        \begin{ansproofbase}\end{ansproofbase}%
    \else%
        \textcolor{NavyBlue}{%
            \begin{ansproofbase}%
                \BODY%
            \end{ansproofbase}%
        }%
    \fi%
}
```

By chatgpt, I tried `\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\BODY}\relax`, which also didn't work.

---- Edit 1: Small Example ----

```
\begin{ansproof}

\end{ansproof}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}
```

Result:
[image: example result]

---- Edit 2: Complete Example ----

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, xcolor, environ, xparse}

\definecolor{NavyBlue}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ansproofbase}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\hfill\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\qed}}%
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textit{#1.}}]\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\NewEnviron{ansproof}{%
    \ifx\BODY\empty%
        \begin{ansproofbase}\end{ansproofbase}%
    \else%
        \textcolor{NavyBlue}{%
            \begin{ansproofbase}%
                \BODY%
            \end{ansproofbase}%
        }%
    \fi%
    \vspace{-0.8em}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Small Example:
\begin{ansproof}
    
\end{ansproof}
\begin{proof}
    
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Complete Example]

---- Edit 3: More Subtle Example ----

(Just add the following to the previous example, inside document)
Using `\if\relax\BODY\relax` instead of `\ifx\BODY\empty` @Steven B. Segletes mentioned in the answer below, the NavyBlue (ans)proof looks exactly like proof in the example above. However, the space isn't trimed inside the `\item` of `\enumerate` environment which is really odd.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Example item
    \begin{ansproof}
    
    \end{ansproof}
    \begin{proof}
        
    \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: Subtle Example Result]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you edit the question to provide a small but complete (compileable) example, so that we have something to play with/test?  Perhaps `\let\n\empty` at some strategic point in your code will rectify the issue.

Comment: sure, I will edit the question, what i want is the black version (original version), with color being NavyBlue. The issue of directly using \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\begin{proof}\end{proof}} is that it will raise an error since the stuff inside proof is empty. (although i don't know why it causes error)

Comment: Except that *complete example* (minimum working example = MWE) begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and compiles directly.

Comment: Editted, thank you for explaining these!

Comment: Please look at my revised answer.  David and egreg both noted significant deficiency in my prior answer.  I believe I have rectified their specific concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David and egreg for pointing out flaws in my original answer(s).

We would like to employ an `\if` test on `\BODY` rather than `\ifx` because we want to test the complete `\BODY` rather than just the first token of `\BODY`.

The problem is that `\BODY`, for the case cited by the OP, contains a lone `\par` in it and the OP would like that circumstance to be treated as an empty `\BODY`.

So here, I perform a token cycle on `\BODY` to (temporarily) eliminate `\par` tokens and then check whether the detokenization of this result is blank. The actual code I use for the test is

```
\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}\relax
```

where `\cytoks` is the token list containing the tokens of `\BODY` with all `\par` tokens excised.

I also moved the `\textcolor` inside the `ansproofbase` environment, to avoid strange spacings in certain circumstances.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, xcolor, environ, xparse,tokcycle}
\Macrodirective{\ifx\par#1\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}

\definecolor{NavyBlue}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ansproofbase}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\hfill\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\qed}}%
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textit{#1.}}]\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\NewEnviron{ansproof}{%
    \expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}\relax%
        \begin{ansproofbase}\end{ansproofbase}%
    \else
        \begin{ansproofbase}%
            \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\BODY}%
        \end{ansproofbase}%
    \fi%
    \vspace{-0.8em}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Small Example:
    \begin{ansproof} \end{ansproof}

    \begin{ansproof}\mbox{x}\end{ansproof}

    \begin{ansproof}

    \end{ansproof}

    \begin{ansproof}
not empty
    \end{ansproof}

    \begin{proof}
        
    \end{proof}

\makeatletter
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Example item with space
    \begin{ansproof} \end{ansproof}

    \item Example item with leading mbox
    \begin{ansproof}\mbox{x}\end{ansproof}

    \item Example item with blank line
    \begin{ansproof}
    
    \end{ansproof}

    \item Example item with text
    \begin{ansproof}
      not empty
    \end{ansproof}

    \item Example item
    \begin{proof}
        
    \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need for the `\expandafter`'s, `\if` expands `\BODY`.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Of course it does...that was the point.  I'll correct it.

Comment: Great answer! However, there is another issue. When I use it in any `\item` inside `\enumerate`, it will still behave like before. I will edit my main question to include this.

Comment: what if the first token of `\BODY` is `\relax`?

Comment: @UdiFogiel yes that is true, and the usefulness of the answer relies on the almost certainty that actual proof text will not begin with the token `\relax`.  Another less likely comparative token may be used in lieu of `\relax` if that is an issue.

Comment: What do you mean with “`\par` will expand to an ignored space”? This is wrong.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you! this is helpful as well!

Comment: `\if\relax\BODY\relax` can't possibly do what you intend, it is true if the first non expandable token of `\BODY` is _any_ command. all non character tokens are equal to `\if`. It is true if `\BODY` is empty or just consists of `\par` it is false if `\BODY` starts with a space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm trying to digest what you are saying.  Yet, I am not able to produce an example that does not give what I intend, regardless of whether `\BODY` contains just a `\par`, starts with a command, a letter, or a space.  I'll keep trying to figure out what you are telling me.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\BODY{\mbox{hello}}\BODY: \if\relax\BODY\relax YES\else NO\fi

\def\BODY{}\BODY: \if\relax\BODY\relax YES\else NO\fi

\def\BODY{ }\BODY: \if\relax\BODY\relax YES\else NO\fi


\end{document}`

Comment: the test if true if \BODY is empty or has `\mbox{hello}` and false if it starts with space, I don't see that as a useful test

Comment: sorry despite the fact that @Twilight accepted this answer I think it's just wrong. The  test is not doing anything useful.

Comment: I now see your point.  In the context of `\BODY` as created by `environ`, the inclusion of a space does not produce an adverse result.  Also, not all macros fail the test (for example, `\today`).  However, I do see that `\mbox` causes the test to fail, so I will see what I can do.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's still wrong. What happens is that `environ` trims spaces around the contents, so in the case when the environment only consists of a blank line, your code succeeds. But it's by accident.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your insight.  I have modified and updated my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your insights and examples. I have modified and updated my answer.

Comment: \today expands to characters in English, if it expanded to an accented letter it would be true or false depending on the font encoding

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the purpose of `ansproofbase` is. Just set the color at the outset.

Using `expl3` is easier: the idea is to strip off `\par` tokens from the body of the environment and see whether only blank spaces remain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor}

\definecolor{NavyBlue}{RGB}{0,0,128}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ansproof}{O{\proofname}+b}{%
  \par\color{NavyBlue}
  \begin{proof}[#1]
  \twilight_if_empty:nF { #2 } { #2 }
  \end{proof}
}{}

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \twilight_if_empty:n { T,F,TF }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \par }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_tmpa_tl { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent Small Example:

\begin{ansproof}
    
\end{ansproof}

Something in between

\begin{ansproof}[Interesting proof]
Here it is!
\end{ansproof}

Something at the end

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is really helpful! (Although I need some time to digest the command.) Thank you so much egreg!

Comment: `\tl_remove_all:Nn` ?

Comment: @JosephWright Too many features are available! 